# Equivalent of OpenSSL base64 enc in Node.js (openssl enc -base64 -d -A)?

Tags: node.js, openssl

There's an API I'm working with that returns data that's gunzipped and double Base64 encoded. I've tried using several of the Base64 libraries in NPM to no avail. Doing each library's equivalent `decodeBase64(decodeBase64(something))` always fails due to the output encoding being faulty.

This work in the shell: `something | openssl enc -base64 -d -A | openssl enc -base64 -d -A | gunzip`. I'm essentially looking for a Node.js approach that behaves exactly the same as `something | openssl enc -base64 -d -A | openssl enc -base64 -d -A | gunzip`.

The following libraries do not work in this situation:
base64
base-64
js-base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to find a library that can handle both string and binary representations of Base64 (which mirrors OpenSSL).

```
const forge = require('node-forge')
const zlib  = require('zlib')

const pass1  = forge.util.decode64('SDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQUNzcEtrMEZBSTFNL1AwRUFBQUE=')
const pass2  = forge.util.binary.base64.decode(pass1)
const result = zlib.gunzipSync(new Buffer(pass2)).toString()

console.log(result) // true
```